# fastapi how to read nested json as dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to receive the following JSON:

```
{
    "va": "{1: 5, 2:1, 3:5}"
}
```

in my main.py I have the following:

```
from typing import Optional, Dict
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class rq(BaseModel):
    va: Dict[str, str]
    

app = FastAPI(debug=True)

@app.post("/hello")
async def create_item(rq: rq):
    return 1
```

but I get

> "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
> "type": "type_error.dict"

how may I receive va as dict to iterate over it?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a model, every field is actually a key-value pair, so with your example it expects something like this:

```
{
    "va": {"some":"value"}
}
```

But what you send is

```
"va": str
```

So i don't know how you send the value but you are definitely sending a **str** instead of a `Dict[str, str]`

Comment: If you are storing in a SQL Alchemy database, store in a JSON column type. Also be sure that you are using json.dumps before saving.